# Impliment Facebook connect phonegap (ios/android)

Tags: facebook, cordova

I am trying to implement facebook connect using phonegap for android/iOS .. But not getting any success.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cordova only not achive this so u need to integrate with native code android means java ios means objective C .... so

[Follow this steps](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You can use that plugin.
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin
I used it a year ago with no problem